# Lisp: TAGBODY issue

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am a beginner in LISP programming and I am unsure how to use tagbody in order to read numbers from the keyboard until I reach a negative number. I tried to find resources available online, however I was unsuccessful so far.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `tagbody` doesn't read from the keyboard; it's a control flow construct. You use it to create a body of statements with labels. Inside that body, you can jump to labeled statements using `go`. `tagbody` can be used to create a loop which repeatedly performs some action, like reading input.

Comment: StackOverflow questions requiring debugging help should include the nonworking code in the question itself, the input and desired output, or description of the desired behavior.

Answer (score 8):

You do *not*.  [`tagbody`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_tagbod.htm) is a very low-level facility.

Use [`do`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_do_do.htm) or [`loop`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_a.htm) instead:

```
(loop for num = (read) while (plusp num) collect num)
```

PS. The compiler might macro-expand my code to a `tagbody` similar to the form in the other answer. In a way, `tagbody` is the "assembly" of Lisp :-)

Answer (score 4):

A good way to approach [`TAGBODY`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_tagbod.htm) and its friend [`PROG`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_prog_.htm) is to consider your algorithm as a finite state-machine. Your function tries to implement the following:

[image]

You could write the following to implement the state machine:

```
(PROG* (N (E (CONS NIL NIL)) (Q (CONS E E)))
   READ-NUMBER
     (SETQ N (READ))
     (IF (MINUSP N)
         (GO FINISH)
         (GO COLLECT))
   COLLECT
     (RPLACD Q (CDR (RPLACD (CDR Q) (CONS N NIL))))
     (GO READ-NUMBER)
   FINISH
     (RETURN (CDAR Q)))
```

I upcased all symbols and used CAR/CDAR/... because like TAGBODY/PROG, that belongs to a style of programming that fell out of fashion decades ago.
A large set of useful state-machines are already abstracted away by [`LOOP`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_loop.htm) or other iterators. That being said, `TAGBODY` is still available and might be useful in rare occasions, hidden behind macros.

Graphviz source

```
digraph abc {

rankdir=LR
nodesep=1

R[label="READ NUMBER"]
C[label="COLLECT"]
F[label="FINISH", penwidth=2]

I[style=invis, width=0]
I -> R [penwidth=0, arrowhead="vee"]

R -> C [label="N ≥ 0"]
C -> R [label="TRUE"]
R -> F [label="N < 0"]

}
```

Comment: all these `setf`s are too fancy! if  going down memory lane already, then go with `setq` & `rplacd`!

Comment: @WillNess Thanks, I changed that.

Comment: CHECK-TYPE is modern, too.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Thanks.